# NullPointerException when starting an activity through intent

Tags: java, android

I have following code, I am truing to start an activity given certain condition is true. But over `startActivity(controllerActivity);` I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

The `controllerActivity` variable at the stage contains a valid value of `Intent { act=android.intent.action.Main }`

```
Thread thr_authenticateUser = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        …
        Boolean _authenticationStatus = Boolean.valueOf(authenticationReplyValue);
        if (_authenticationStatus) {
            Intent controllerActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.Main");
            startActivity(controllerActivity); //NullPointerException
        }
    }
});
thr_authenticateUser.start();
```

Over further findings I found out that the exact place where it is failing is inside Main activitY’s `onCreate()

```
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view); // HERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However the view name `main_view` is correct and it exists.
`Manifest:`

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Compelte stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
        at com.citypulse.citypulse.User$1.run(User.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: *"android.intent.action.Main"*. ?

Comment: what is R in R.layout.main_view?

Comment: Are you certain the NULL pointer is on the setContentView? I didn't think you could call getWindow() before setting the content view.

Comment: yes its there. is it ok for `savedInstanceState` object to be null?

Comment: It's fine for state to be null. Try commenting out `setContentView` and see if it works then.

Comment: I would comment out the getWindow as I believe it is the actual cause.

Comment: just checked through both your suggestions `setContentView ` is the real cause and i dont know why

Comment: Your problem is here: "com.citypulse.citypulse.User$1.run(User.java:57)". Please post the code for `User.java` and indicate what line 57 is.

Comment: The problem here is that the activities `Context` is not set up properly. You are doing something strange in the instantiation of the `Activity` itself. Either you are creating it with `new` or you are mucking around in the constructor.

Comment: what part of code you want to see.. i posted most the things i considered relevant.

Comment: Do you have a constructor in `User.java`? Are you creating an instance of `User` class using `new`?

Comment: Your manifest shows an Activity called `Main`, but your stack trace shows a class called `User`. What is `User`?

Comment: [Your question, it has a same answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971065/unable-to-start-activity-through-intent-activitynotfoundexception/27971132#27971132

Answer (score 0):

Get the context to start your activity

```
getBaseContext().startActivity(controlledActivity);
```

or

```
YourActivity.this.startActivity(controlledActivity);
```

Comment: same result with this change

Comment: And if you do it like this:  `Intent i = new Intent(context,ControllerActivity.class)`

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine the way it is. Can you post the whole code? And why the downvote?