# Unable to start activity through intent: ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this `Activity` defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I am trying to call it in this way:

```
Intent splashActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.Splash");
mainAppContext.startActivity(splashActivity);
```

I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.Splash }
```

And when I try to start it in this way:

```
Intent splashActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN ");
mainAppContext.startActivity(splashActivity);
```

It open a `Complete action using` dialog with many options there like play store etc.
Please help in starting this `Activity`.

Comment: Which activity you want start from? I mean from where to splashActivity?

Comment: Stop trying to start activities implicitly, in fact in 5.0 you get an error if you do this

Comment: Seriously? Basic Android lesson: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent splashActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.Splash");
```

No-no-no!  It should to

```
Intent splashActivity = new Intent(context, Splash.class);
```

If you use action - it seem that you want activity for some type of action, for example, view webpage on browser.
In your situation you have to use concrete activity and set it to intent

---

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

this action is not for your app, it is needed to android's launcher, that find activity in your application to launch it

[Official documentation about intent mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 1):

From some other Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Splash.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to launch this activity from? The following lines imply that `Splash` is your main `Activity`:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Are you trying to launch the `Splash` `Activity` from `Splash` itself? This would be problematic. If you are launching from another `Activity` then you can use the following to launch `Splash`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(YourCurrentActivity.this, Splash.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity not found exception is occurred when u are trying to use or start activity that is not declared  into the Mainfeast.xml  file.

And When you want to start any activity then you need to start that activity by using intent. but in android "android.intent.action.Splash" Intent Action exist. And you have declared the following intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

"android.intent.action.MAIN" this is the action name that indicate the this is the activity to be started first. and android send this intent and an activity that is registered with this intent action is the first activity to be started first.
So to start splash activity you doesn't need any intent. You just need to simply run this project. but If u want to Start Another activity from splash actiivty then u need to do following things.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Context, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent); 
or 
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

and remember that You have to declare that activity into the mainfeast.xml